# How to iterate through a list of TreeMap in FTL

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, jvm, freemarker

I'm trying to write a code to generate JVM thread dump using FTL and I have a problem iterating through a TreeMap.

This is a snippet of my action class:

-----Start------

```
public AppsnapAction() {
    traces = new TreeMap<Thread, StackTraceElement[]>(COMP);
    traces.putAll(Thread.getAllStackTraces());
}
```

The method in question.

```
public Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> getAppTraces() {
 //  log.debug("HelloMe..in getAppTraces"+ traces);
    return traces;
}
```

----End--------

And this is the snippet of the FTL:

-----Start-----

```
<h1>My Trace</h1>
<#list appTraces?keys as trace>
<h4><a name="${trace_index}">${trace}</a></h4>
<pre>
<#list appTraces[trace] as traceline>
   at ${traceline}
</#list>
</pre>
    </#list>
```

------End-------

The code breaks at this line: 
 "<#list appTraces[trace] as traceline>"

with the following exception:

2013-09-15 22:58:35,701 [http-8080-1] ERROR freemarker.runtime -

get(Thread[ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]],5,main]) failed on instance of java.util.TreeMap
  The problematic instruction:

---

==> list appTraces[trace] as traceline [on line 42, column 5 in /resources/templates/td-Page.ftl]

---

Java backtrace for programmers:

---

```
freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: get(Thread[ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]],5,main]) failed on instance of java.util.TreeMap
at freemarker.ext.beans.BeanModel.get(BeanModel.java:223)
at freemarker.core.DynamicKeyName.dealWithStringKey(DynamicKeyName.java:136)
at freemarker.core.DynamicKeyName._getAsTemplateModel(DynamicKeyName.java:94)
at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:94)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:213)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Thread
at com.jivesoftware.helloworld.action.AppsnapAction$1.compare(AppsnapAction.java:1)
at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(TreeMap.java:351)
at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:322)
at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:255)
at freemarker.ext.beans.MapModel.invokeGenericGet(MapModel.java:127)
at freemarker.ext.beans.BeanModel.get(BeanModel.java:185)
... 202 more
```

Any thoughts on how to iterate through the inner loop please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just hit one of the top FreeMarker annoyances: The `[]` operator doesn't support non-string keys, at least until FreeMarker 2.4. So until that the easiest workaround is probably changing the object wrapper to a `BeansWrapper` that has `simpleMapWrapper` on. Like,  `new BeansWrapper(); bw.setSimpleMapWrapper(true); Configuration.setObjectWrapper(bw);`. This wrapper provides this hack: `appTraces(trace)`. `myMap[stringKey]` and `myMap.foo` will still work. The downside is that if you already have a lot of templates, some of them might breaks as the data-model will look *slightly* differently now. Or a lot different, depending on what object wrapper are you using now... Anyway, if you are coming from the default object wrapper, it usually doesn't break anything, unless you have XML in the data-model.